# como saber fila de tabla seleccionada

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo mi Tabla `html`:

```html
  <div class="container">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" @*style="width:1200px"*@>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>                       
                        <th style="width: 15%;">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="empleado">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>                    
                    </tr>
               </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

Con un boton secundario mando llamar una `function` en `js`, donde me regresa una lista y lleno mi tabla sin problema, y por cada fila en la columna accion, creo un boton llamado `actualizar`, este es mi `js`:

```
function empleado() {
    var xxxxx = document.getElementById('xxxx').value;

    var datos = { xxxx: xxx };
    console.log(datos);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/xxx/xxxx?xx=' + xx,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
        .done(function (lista) {
            console.log(lista);
            $('#empleado').empty();
            for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
                console.log(i);
                $('#empleado').append(//recorremos la lista llenando la tabla
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + lista[i]._nombre + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + lista[i]._apellido + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + lista[i]._direccion + '</td>' +
                    '<td><button id="actualizar" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="Actualizar()">Actualizar</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                );
            }
        });
}
```

mi tabla se llena sin problema, y en cada fila el objetivo de el boton actualizar es que despliegue un modal, con `inputs` con informacion cargada previamente para poder modificar

El problema que tengo es como puedo mandar llamar la informacion perteneciente a cada fila?

```
function Actualizar() {
 $('#MyModalActualizar').modal('show');

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

En la función Actualizar del evento onclick deberías pasar como parámetro el valor ID de cada registro.

```
<button id="actualizar" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="Actualizar(' + lista[i]._id + ')">
```

La función Actualizar podría utilizar el id para recoger los datos de dicho registro.

```
function Actualizar(id) {
    //TODO: Mediante una consulta ajax deberias recuperar los datos del registro usando el id
    $('#MyModalActualizar').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo mi consulta por medio de AJAX ya la integre pero al dar click en actualizar me manda esto 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' en index 1 <!DOCTYPE html>